# bad css causing really bad layout on small devices

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I built a website with Foundation 4 and having some issues (lots of them) with the responsive part of it, decided to get rid of the viewports in the CSS which I thought would cause the website to render normally on small devices but the result is really bad and I'm not sure what's causing it. I have no more @media targetting small devices in the CSS and yet it still very very messed up.

You can look at the results on different devices there:
http://www.viewlike.us/

This is my website
http://broadcasted.tv/

Can anyone tell me what's wrong ? (Javascript or something ? I don't know, but it's bad...)
**Is there a way to tell the browser to ignore diffferent width and handle everything the same way ?**
Thanks

Comment: You removed the viewports and @media queries that are supposed to make it look good on mobile.  If something looked bad before you needed to fix that within the media queries... Not delete them all together.

Comment: I tried that and I just ended up spending hours and hours on bad fixes. Shouldn't having no media queries mean having the same css ?

Comment: Is there a way to tell the browser to ignore diffferent width and handle everything the same way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) for your header and divs so they don't become smaller than the desired size, I see something like that happens to your header.

For example, I just tried adding *min-width:1100px;* to your *top-bar* div, and there seems to be less of a problem in that part.

I'm not saying having a 1100px header is recommended (because it's not) but I'm just using it as an example.

Comment: I know it's not idea but I think that's gonna have to be that way until I can spend a lot more time on it. Thanks

Comment: A layout with 1100px as width will look too big for mobile devices and small screens,  that’s what those `@media` you removed are for, adjusting the CSS to different screens.

If you are going to use the same CSS for every device, I would recommend at least using a smaller width to make it less painful for those with small screens (unless your website audience is more laptop/desktop oriented) 

You can take a look here for more about the use of `@media` when you’re ready for it: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 1):

don't delete the @media queries, they are what is used to display things differently for each device. If you're trying to ignore different screen resolutions, you're not using responsive design.

EDIT: looking at your website, it seems to be fine for resolutions 1041+... with that knowledge, use those @media queries to get rid of that giant bar on the side.